# How to install java on Suse?

Tags: java, linux, suse

I'm trying to install java (jre 1.8) on **Linux Suse**,

I've downloaded the tar.gz file from oracle website and unzipped it.

Now I have java on my machine but I can only run it like that:

```
./java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

running the command by itself doesn't work:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin # java -version
If 'java' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found java
-bash: java: command not found
```

[image]

So obviously I can't add to the PATH because it will not be recognized.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Comment: You need to add the directory `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin` to your executable search path. `export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin:${PATH}`. I'm not familar with Suse, but in your user home there should be some `.profile` file where you can add this setting. If you want to change it for all users have a look for a file `/etc/profile`.

Comment: But how does it make sense to add it to the PATH if it's not running as it should from the "bin" directory itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux is not Windows. If you start a executable without a path the system will start it only if it's found in one of the directories specified in `PATH`.

This means even if the executable you want to run is in your current directory it would not be executed if this directory is not in `PATH`. If you explicitly specify the directory the executable will be executed even the directory it's not in `PATH`.

See some small examples.

Following s assumed: `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin` is not specified in `PATH`.

```
cd /tmp
java
```

Would fail as `/tmp` is not in `PATH`.

```
cd /tmp
./java
```

Would fail as there is (normally) no `java` executable in the `/tmp` directory.

```
cd /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin
java
```

Would fail as `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin` is not in `PATH`.

```
cd /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin
./java
```

Would be executed as you explicitly specify to run `java` found in the current directory `./`.

Comment: In Suse you need  to Add /etc/profile.local and the PATH addition will survive upgrades for the regular users. For root check the .profile located in /etc

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan Thanks for adding this information, related for Suse. As the location and file names might be different depending on the used Linux distribution.